# ANTLR - Why do unused lexical rules have an influence on the function of the grammar?

Tags: antlr, antlr4

So I'm trying to parse the following text file:

```
    555 5555
```

With this grammar:

```
grammar PEntry;

entry               : Tab Number Nl;

Tab : '\t';
Nl : '\n';

Number          : Num RSp Num RSp;
//Name       : (RWord RSp)+;

fragment RWord      : (~[\p{Z}])+;
fragment Num        : [0-9]+;
fragment RSp        : [\p{Z}]+;
```

Through the commandline like so:

```
grun PEntry entry test.txt -gui
```

What's throwing me off is that, if you leave the Name rule commented, it parses it perfectly fine, but if the Name rule is uncommented, the following error occurs:

```
line 1:0 mismatched input '\t555 5555 ' expecting '   '
```

Why does this happen, when Name isn't even referenced in the target rule (entry)? In a context-free grammar, any unused rules that are not referenced by the start variable are not in the language at all, so what makes antlr different?

Update: (~[\p{Z}])+ was supposed to be [~\p{Z}]+, but shouldn't this rule still have no effect on the grammar? I want to know if there's some way that antlr parses rules that makes it different from a CFG.

Answer (score 1):

The lexer works independently from the parser, it doesn't know which lexer rules are used by the parser and which aren't. How the lexer works is that it looks at all the lexer rules that you defined<sup>1</sup> and then picks the one that produces the longest match on the current input (in case of ties it picks the one that is defined first). So that's why adding a new lexer rule - especially one that produces long matches - can change the result.

The whole parser works in two steps: The lexer and then the actual parser. The lexer turns the source, which is a sequence of characters, into a sequence of tokens and then the parser turns the sequence of tokens into parse tree by parsing them according to the parser rule. The parser rules *do* act as a CFG, but the lexer rules aren't a part of that CFG. Instead the tokens are the terminals of the CFG and the token rules only affect the process of producing said tokens - a process that is independent of the parser rules.

---

<sup>1</sup> Unless you're using modes, in which case it will only look at the ones in the current mode.

Comment: Or differently put: all lexer rules (within the same mode) act as if they were alternatives in a single big top level rule, which is why also a single leading lexer predicate will affect speed of all lexer rules pretty badly.