# Why adding an unused rule changes the output of an ANTLR grammar?

Tags: antlr4

File Hello.g4:

```
grammar Hello;

entry
  :  headword EOF
  ;

headword
  :  LETTER (LETTER)*
  ;

LETTER : [a-zA-Z] ;
```

The above grammar matches the input `apple` in file abc.txt:

```
apple
```

```
C:\Code\antlr\hello>antlr4 Hello.g4 -encoding utf8

C:\Code\antlr\hello>javac Hello*.java

C:\Code\antlr\hello>type abc.txt | java org.antlr.v4.gui.TestRig Hello entry -tree -encoding utf8
(entry (headword a p p l e) <EOF>)
```

So far so good. Now if I add the following at the end of Hello.g4:

```
unused_rule
  :  'a'
  |  'b'
  |  'c'
  |  'd'
  |  'e'
  |  'f'
  ;
```

The result is quite unexpected:

```
C:\Code\antlr\hello>type abc.txt | java org.antlr.v4.gui.TestRig Hello entry -tree -encoding utf8
line 1:0 extraneous input 'a' expecting LETTER
line 1:4 extraneous input 'e' expecting <EOF>
(entry (headword a p p l) e <EOF>)
```

1. Why are the 'a' and 'e' not matched?
2. Why is the 'a' at the beginning of 'apple' included in `headword` while the 'e' is not? They are both considered 'extraneous input'.
3. Why the addition of an unused parser rule changes grammar behaviour? My (rather premature and Prolog-biased) understading of how ANTLR might work tells me that an unused parser rule would never be evaluated and should not affect the output.
4. Where can I get (free) information about how ANTLR works, i.e. how rules are evaluated, order, precedence of rules / alternatives? The official docs (e.g. [Parser Rules](https://github.com/antlr/antlr4/blob/master/doc/parser-rules.md)) focus more on syntax rather than the runtime evaluation of grammar rules.

NB. I have seen [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/56744605/1291717) very similar question about *lexer* rules. Mine is about the unused *parser* rule.

Answer (score 3):

Using literal tokens inside your parser rule:

```
unused_rule
  :  'a'
  |  'b'
  |  'c'
  |  'd'
  |  'e'
  |  'f'
  ;
```

results in ANTLR creating the following lexer rules:

```
T_1 : 'a';
T_2 : 'b';
T_3 : 'c';
T_4 : 'd';
T_5 : 'e';
T_6 : 'f';
LETTER : [a-zA-Z] ;
```

Which means that the chars `a..f` will never become a `LETTER`.

If you want to use certain characters, like `a..f`, inside other rules, but also want them to be a `LETTER`, then do something like this:

```
headword
 : letter+
 ;

letter
 : A
 | B
 | C
 | D
 | E
 | F
 | LETTER
 ;


A : 'a';
B : 'b';
C : 'c';
D : 'd';
E : 'e';
F : 'f';

LETTER : [a-zA-Z];
```

Comment: Thanks again for sharing your insights. Is there a way to tell it _not_ to create the anonymous lexer tokens? My grammar is very context-dependent and the same char ('a') will have different meanings in different contexts.

Comment: No, ANTLR has a strict separation between parser and lexer. The lexer works independently from the parser. No way around this.

Comment: @SergeySlepov checkout my edited answer.

Comment: I see where you are going with this. But how do I scale it up from single chars to char sequences? E.g. if I want 'to' and 'for' to be a ```preposition``` (in certain contexts), will I need to add TO and FOR to ```letter```? So basically for any letter sequence that appears anywhere else in my grammar I will need to remember to add it to ```letter```? And then deal with 'form' tokenized as FOR 'm'? That sounds like a lot of extra work...

Comment: I imagine this problem should be nothing new. E.g. in the C grammar ```Identifier``` is defined using ```Nondigit : [a-zA-Z_]``` which does not conflict with C keywords such as 'for' or 'while'. Is 'fragment' the key to the solution? https://github.com/antlr/grammars-v4/blob/master/c/C.g4#L599-L616

Comment: No, `while` and `for` are never going to be an `Identifier`. The problem you have is that you promote the creation of a identifier (you call it a `headword`) to the parser instead of the lexer. Another problem with that approach is that when/if you ignore white spaces, the lexer will produce 2 `LETTER` tokens for the input `a b` (`a` SPACE `b`). And if you ignore/discard spaces in the lexer, the `a` and `b` tokens separated by a space will become a valid `headword` in your parser.

Comment: "And then deal with 'form' tokenized as FOR 'm'? That sounds like a lot of extra work...", yes, you should not have a parser rule that creates an identiefer/headword to begin with. If you do, then ANTLR might not be the right tool for you. Google for "PEG", or "scannerless parser" instead.